# jQuery: difficult to add a symbol

Tags: jquery

I do not know much about jQuery, that`s why I would like to ask you to help me to a add to my script the symbol of DOLLAR ($) as text. Need to mention that the script is working without dollar.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function($){
var money = parseFloat($("#INSERTMONEY").val());
$('#costline').val((money).toFixed(2).text("$"));
})
</script>
```

In my opinion I do something wrong by adding this - **.text("$")**. I would much appreciete your contribution. Thank in advance.

Comment: `$('#costline').val( '$' +  money.toFixed(2) );`?

Comment: `toFixed` returns a string. Strings don't have a `.text` method (jQuery objects have one http://api.jquery.com/text/). What you can use is string concatenation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/String_Operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('#costline').val((money).toFixed(2) +"$");
```

Explanation:
You are calling the `text()` function on the money variable which is a string after applying `tofixed()` to it and does not have this function.
What you want to do is add a dollar sign, so concatenating a float and a string. This is done with the `+`

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var money = parseFloat($("#INSERTMONEY").val());
    $('#costline').val('$' + (money).toFixed(2));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var money = parseFloat($("#INSERTMONEY").val());
  $('#costline').val("$"+(money).toFixed(2));
});
```

If this is an input/textarea you use the val function like above, but if its a div or other element, you change it to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var money = parseFloat($("#INSERTMONEY").text());
  $('#costline').text("$"+(money).toFixed(2));
});
```